# How to return data directly to a client who queried via an intermediate server

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to figure out a way of taking a shortcut in the following process:

1. client side javascript sends an XMLHttpRequest to a.com/core.php
2. core.php requests the data from b.com/api.php via file_get_contents()
3. data is sent from b.com to a.com
4. data is sent from a.com to the client

The process works flawlessly, but it seems to me that there is optimization potential in the way the data is returned to the client - passing the data back via a.com serves no practical purpose.

Is there a way to make b.com send the data directly to the client? And if so, what information has to be passed from a.com to b.com?

Diagram for clarification: 
[image]

Comment: Since server B has no awareness of the client and has not received a request from that client Server B cannot send data directly to that client.

Comment: perhaps you can look in to making your ajax call directly to server B, if cross domain is an option

Comment: In my case, that is not an option, as A has to append the API key to the request.
I thought there might be a possibility to forward the connection information (IP or whatever), but appearantly that's not possible.

@Pevara Thanks for appending the image!

Comment: I think it should be possible to set up a websocket connection between the client and server B. Then the client could send a request to server A triggering server A to send a request to server B triggering server B to send data over the websocket connection with the client. Its complicated. I don't know if it would be worth the effort. The old way of doing it is much simpler.